# Eclipse Maven Project points throws File.not.Found error

Tags: java, java-io

Hi Guys I am having an File inside src/main/resources/CustomersDetails.txt but i am getting an java.io.FileNotFoundException.  But the Url is not null and my if condition is true but my eclipse throws me the following error: Why it is looking on target and in my target folder i have only the jar and my file is also present on the target folder Any ideas?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Balachander%20K\eclipse-workspace\JavaLearning\target\classes\CustomersDetails.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at com.syncfusion.Persons.main(Persons.java:22)
```

My Program:

```
package com.syncfusion;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Persons {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persons person = new Persons();
        try {

            File file = person.getFileNameFromResources("CustomersDetails.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line=bufferedReader.readLine();
            while(line!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private File getFileNameFromResources(String fileName) {

        ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = loader.getResource(fileName);
        if(url!=null) {
            System.out.println("File Found");
            return new File(url.getFile());
        }
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to duplicate your program with Maven and running it with Eclipse, I got it to work!

Did you import your Maven project correctly? 
When I import the Maven project into Eclipse, it will generate the target folder and place it in the correct path (target\classes\CustomerDetails.txt).

My second guess is that you probably added the txt file after importing the project into eclipse? In this way, it might not get compiled correctly?

You can either delete the project in eclipse (don't delete contents on disk) and delete the "target" folder, then import it again.

Or you can compile your mvn from the terminal,

```
mvn compile
mvn package
```

go back to your eclipse (right click --> refresh your project).

Comment: Hi @yuvan i created maven project and later created the text file.  I tried all your methods but it doesn't worked for me any other ways?

Comment: That's weird.. because it worked perfectly fine for me.
How do you import your Maven project into eclipse? Do you have the whole project? (src and target folder) or do you just have the folder that contains java files?

Comment: The way I did it is as below:
1. Create the maven project and add the Persons class
2. Add the text file into src/main/resources/CustomersDetails.txt (at this point there are no "target" folder)
3. Import it to Eclipse (After you import, you will see the "target" folder and txt file in "target\classes" in eclipse)

This worked for me when I run it.

Comment: HI @Yuvan i usually import by using that import  menu available on eclipse but before importing i did a mvn clean and then imported  and i didn't find any .txt in my target in eclipse but it is there in the eclipse-workspace directory but not showing inside eclipse

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the project in your eclipse? Since it is in your workspace directory, if the project is linked to the same directory, it should show up after you do a refresh.